# What's the most efficient way of tracking the state of an application?

Tags: python, error-handling, state

I have a class that keeps track of its state in various ways.

```
self.updates_available = True
self.name = "Something"
self.ERROR = True
```

I run through the functions of the class first checking the state. For example, if there has been an error in the process, there's no need to continue. Or if there are no updates available, don't perform certain functions.

```
 if not myclass.ERROR:
        myclass.do_something()

 if not build.ERROR:
        myclass.do_something_else()

 if not build.ERROR:
        myclass.do_even_more()
```

This can't be the best way to do this. So the question is what's a better way to keep track of the state of the application.

Comment: As above, `myclass.do_something()` and the other methods should throw exceptions if something goes wrong. Then you can catch those at whatever level is appropriate and probably not worry about it at this level.

Comment: Thanks. EAFP seems basically what I'm doing so now that I know it's a legitimate coding style, I suppose I'll continue this way.